# Перестроение диаграммы в Excel при изменении названия в шапке

Tags: excel, vba, excel-формулы

Как можно сделать так, что при изменении названия в шапке диаграммы, она перестраивалась?
Например у меня есть таблица с результатами за год, мне нужно чтобы при изменении года в названии диаграммы, она перестраивалась соответственно таблице?

Другими словами, можно ли как то привязать название диаграммы к таблице?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, например, так. Название диаграммы ввести в виде формулы как ссылку на ячейку (выделить название, кликнуть в строку формул, там ввести `=` и кликнуть на ячейку листа) - см. скриншот ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ячейка нам нужна, чтобы обработать событие изменения ячейки.
В обработчике события `Worksheet_Change` **обязательно в модуле листа** пишем что-то вроде:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$D$1" Then
        Dim diag As Chart, tabl As ListObject
        Set diag = Me.ChartObjects(1).Chart
        Set tabl = Me.ListObjects(1)
        
        m = Application.Match(Trim(Target.Value2), tabl.HeaderRowRange, 0)
        If IsNumeric(m) Then
            diag.SetSourceData Source:=tabl.ListColumns(m).DataBodyRange
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Теперь, изменяя значение года в ячейке `D1`, мы получаем синхронное изменение заголовка таблицы, а также изменение диапазона данных для ряда диаграммы.

> Но, на мой взгляд, это довольно громоздко. Проще менять год, например,
> по двойному клику на шапке таблицы - в какой колонке клик произошел, тот год и выводить на диаграмме

Answer (score 0):

**На листе**

В `D1` - выпадающий список с годами (*Данные-Проверка данных-Проверка данных-Список, Источник* - диапазон из шапки таблицы).

В `D2` вписать формулу (и протянуть вниз):

```
=ГПР($D$1;$A$1:$B$13;СТРОКА();)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**В диаграмме**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если легенда не отображается, имя ряда можно не писать.

Выделить название диаграммы, в строке формул - `=Лист1!$D$1`

Гистограмма будет перестраиваться при изменении в ячейке `D1`. При желании доп. данные можно "накрыть" гистограммой, оставив видимой ячейку с выпадающим списком.